# Call to undefined function get_instance in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, simpletest

I use Simpletest to write a test class. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
  require_once '../simpletest/autorun.php';
  class Exam extends UnitTestCase {
    private $CI;
    function testUser() {
      $this->CI = & get_instance();
      $this->CI->load->model('user_model');
      $this->assertTrue($this->CI->user_model->listAll());
    }
  }
```

But when I excute this script. There's an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_instance() in 
D:\xampp\htdocs\simpleCI\test\exam.php on line 10
```

Why is get_instance undefined and how can I make it available?

Comment: Did you ever get and answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpletest is not part of CodeIgniter. Extending UnitTestCase won't inherit anything from CI. Maybe you can try this library:https://github.com/ericbarnes/codeigniter-simpletest

Comment: Thank you for answer, I've used it, but I don't know how to but when I run file test_users_model.php I have another problem :

Fatal error: Class 'CodeIgniterUnitTestCase' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\simpleCI\tests\models\test_users_model.php on line 3

And I don't know how to write a simple test with simpletest. Can you show me a small test demo, please ?